# Content alignment in dropdown selector

Tags: html, css, alignment, selector, dropdown

I have created a dropdown selector for selecting the suitable quantity of a product.

```
<div class="newSelectQty" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 1;">
                <select id="quantitySelector" class="quantityWrapper">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
```

And I have styled them in the way as following, and I have changed the arrow in the selector with a sprite image.

```
.newSelectQty select{
background: transparent url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat right center;
background-position: 0 -35px; width: 30px;
width: 75px;
text-align: center;
color:#777777;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
height:25px; }
```

And the outcome is like this:
[image]

How can I make the arrow align the the right side while the value (1,2,3,4,5) can have some spaces in the right side such that it is not too close to the left border? And how can I align the selector box in the centre with the word "Quantity"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Use select2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, check this.

```css
#selectbox{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;  
width:auto; 
height:25px; 
}
.newSelectQty select{
background:url(http://s30.postimg.org/simmn8cg1/down_arrow.png) no-repeat right;
width: 75px;
text-align: center;
padding-left:10px;
color:#777777;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
height:25px; 
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-position-x: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.newSelectQty option{
text-indent:10px; 
}
.qnt{
margin-right:5px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectbox">
<label class="qnt">Quantity</label>
<div class="newSelectQty" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 1;">
<select id="quantitySelector" class="quantityWrapper">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check it. I don't understand is I'm correct or wrong.

```css
.formBox{
  display: block; 
}
label,
 select{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(http://rgb.vn/ideas/wp-content/themes/rgb2014/images/iconArrow_on.png);
  background-position: right 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
select option{
  padding: 4px 0; /* Firefox only */
}
```

```html
<div class="formBox">
  <label>Quantity:</label>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```